# Angular Binding in Object Property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How can I make the binding works for object properties. For example in my controller I have:

```
$scope.reviews = {
  rating_summary: 4,
  items: [ { title: 'A Title'}, etc...  ]
}
```

And in my view:

```
<li ng-repeat="review in reviews.items">
```

Now, whenever i change the reviews variables in the controller, nothing is updated:

```
$scope.reviews = [new updated reviews]
```

Probably beacause angular is listening for changes on the old reference of $scope.reviews.

There are two solutions for the binding to work, but both are not very clever:

1. Attach the items to the scope directly, so it would be `$scope.items = $scope.reviews.items`, Now whenever the items are changed they would be updated.
2. User angular.copy to keep the destination reference, so `angular.copy({items: []}, $scope.reviews);`

Are there any other solutions to accomplish this other than the above.

Comment: It should work like #scope.reviews = []new updated reviews]... the problem should be somewhere else... and could u create a plunker for demonstrate...

Comment: it would have worked if scope.reviews is an array, but it's an object and the array is one of the object key, i.e. $scope.reviews = { rating_summary: 5, items: [ item1, item2, ..] }

Comment: Check my example: https://jsfiddle.net/or66quta/

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz sorry man my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work there must be some mistake while updating the object/items
Please refer this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w41R8i0eJy6VdPAGiAPf?p=preview)

```
$scope.reviews = {
    rating_summary: 4,
    items: [ { title: 'A Title'}, { title: 'B Title'}  ]
  };

  $scope.changeItems = function(){
    $scope.reviews.items = [ { title: 'A Title'}, { title: 'B Title'},
                             { title: 'C Title'}];
  };

  $scope.changeObject = function(){
    $scope.reviews = {
    rating_summary: 4,
    items: [ { title: 'A Title'}, { title: 'B Title'}, { title: 'D Title'}  ]
  };
```

Comment: it actually does work, I had problems with other parts of the code, sorry